# HD Wallet Child Private Key Derivation Function

Tags: wallet, development, bip32-hd-wallets

I was trying to understand the specs on **CKD** function from both the **bip32** standard and Mastering Bitcoin book, I couldn't understand how a private key *is derived from the left side of the extended key.*

The book just says the right side becomes the chain code and the left side becomes the private key, after some research online I read someone using terms like **tweaks** and **modulus n**,  **G** which are confusing me since they were not mentioned in the book and not so much in the specification itself.

Please help me clarify on how exactly *a private key is derived from the left side of output*, and the relationship with all those non mentioned parts like the **modulus n** (Which  n?), **tweak** (??), **multiply by G** ( What's G?) since all these terms are not well documented.

Comment: N and G are fixed parameters of the secp256k1 curve. Specifically `N=115792089237316195423570985008687907852837564279074904382605163141518161494337` and `G=(55066263022277343669578718895168534326250603453777594175500187360389116729240, 32670510020758816978083085130507043184471273380659243275938904335757337482424)`

Answer (score 2):

A private key is a number, a very big 256 bit number. You can do ordinary arithmetic on such numbers, for example addition modulo n, where n is the order of the curve (someone else will have to expand on that if needed). n is very close to but less than 2^256.

Here's a diagram of the child private key derivation:

[image]

The left 256 bits of the 512 bit hash is added *modulo n* to the parent private key. The sum, which is also a 256 bit number (because of modulo n), is the child private key. The sum of the parent private key and a seemingly random 256 bit number is a seemingly random 256 bit number, so that sum will function just fine as a private key.

Comment: All operations are modulo the curve order N not modulo 2^256

Comment: Thanks, @MikeD. Updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: From that image we can deduce that childPrivateKey= leftSideHash + parentPrivateKey ?. Correct me if I'm wrong. From that relation where's n or G used?

Comment: @TheOverloadGenius n is used in the addition (addition modulo n). It says "Normal addition" in the figure but it's actually "Normal addition modulo n". Maybe I should add that to the figure. G is not used at all in child private key derivation. It's only used when calculating a public key from a private key.